# NInject: Send parameter to ViewModel Class Constructor

Tags: xaml, mvvm, ninject

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 app and am using the MVVM pattern. I have a need to pass a parameter to the contructor of the ViewModel for a page. All my datacontexts and binding are done in XAML. Through my research I've seen that I need to do so using a dependency injector such as NInject.

Here's a little detail on whats going on:
I have a page with a ListPicker that lists various tasks. Each task has a unique TaskID. When an item is selected I need to open another page that will show the selected Tasks detail. My ViewModel and binding is all done and works if I use a static TaskID in the ViewModel but of course I need to use a variable.

I've setup NInject in the project and the various classes needed such as ViewModelLocator and my NInjectModule as shown here:

```
public class LighthouseNInjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<TaskViewModel>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("TaskID", 2690);
    }
}
```

Note that I have hardcoded a TaskID here and using this code this value properly gets injected into my constructor. Of course, this is hardcoded and I need to get the TaskID for the selected ListPicker item. I know how to get the selected ID from the ListPicker but how do I make NInject aware of it so when my class constructor is run it will have the correct value?

Here is the basic definition of my ViewModel class showing use of the Injector attribute.

```
public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Inject]
    public TaskViewModel(int TaskID)
    {
        //run function to get data using TaskID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WithConstructorArgument` has another oveload that accepts a lazy evaluated `Func<Context, object>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Remo. I've been all over GitHub for Ninject and here as well looking to see how and where that gets implemented but have come up empty. The docs for Ninject are very thin, I wish there was a good book explaining everything. Does anyone have a sample?

Comment: @Waltedbn: Can you explain what version you're on/difficulty you're having? Remo's approach is correct, and from memory that overload has been in Ninject for a long time. You not seeing the overload? What are you seeing? We can't herlp more unless you can give more detail on your exact issue. Re books, Dependency Injection in .NET is highly recommended although it specifically does not cover Ninject. If you read that and the Ninject wiki, you'll have sufficient info. (Not saying the wiki is perfect - it depends on the mix of intro material / ninject specifics you need and its far from perfect)

Comment: Thanks for the book reccomendation. Theres a new version coming out at the end of August and I've placed the order. As for my current issue, I see the overload that takes "string name, Func<iContext,object> callback" as the arguments. 
Where I'm having problems is the callback argument. I'm assuming that needs to be a function in the viewModel that has the value that needs to be sent to the ctor of the second viewModel.

Comment: Do I specify a delegate to the function? The function name itself? Do I use a lambda such as ()=>MyDelegate. I've done a lot of reading the last day re Func's, delegates, callbacks but can not get any syntax I use to compile. Obviously I do not have much experience using a func callback as an argument and am searching for a sample implementation.

Comment: E.g. `WithConstructorArgument("TaskID", ctx => 23);`

Comment: Or you pass in the argument on the Get `kernel.Get<X>(new ConstructorArgument("TaskID", 23)`. But do this only using a factory implementation and not from the productive code directly.

Comment: Those examples send in a static value which I'm able to do already but as previously stated, thats not what I'm trying to figure out. I'm trying to implement your previous suggestion about using the func<> argument. This supposedly would let me get a value from one viewModel and sending it to the contructor of another.

Comment: Replace 23 by myFunctionToGetTheTaskIdOfThePageIWantToOpen()

Comment: @Remo you've been quite helpful as well as patient with me but I've tried that too. Specifying ctx => GetIDFunction() gives errors such as 'delegate does not take 1 arg','can not covert lambda as not delegate', 'obj ref req for non-static'. If I do ctx => new MyVM.GetIDFunction() that compiles but creates new instance of VM not bound to my View so it can't get the required value. I've stepped through the code to verify this. And the VM's can not be made static. I saw your posting on my other message so I will work on that suggestion. Again, I greatly appreciate your time and knowledge on this.